# Contar Dentro de un Array

Tags: javascript

Quiero contar solo un tipo de producto, cual es la mejor manera de hacer, Ejemplo quiero que me imprima el numero de "ORANGE" = 2 y no todo el array:

```
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];
fruits.length;

console.log(fruits.length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter):

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];
var naranjas = fruits.filter(function(value, index) {return value == "Orange";})
console.log(naranjas.length);
```

Primero filtras todos los resultados que sean `"Orange"` y luego imprimes el largo. Basicamente se está creando un sub-array del array original.

O con la nueva notación:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];
var naranjas = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit == "Orange")
console.log(naranjas.length);
```

**Actualización:**

Se me ocurre que para contar las frutas lo más sencillo es crear un objeto que guarde las cantidades:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];
var fruits_counter = {};

fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
  if (!fruits_counter.hasOwnProperty(fruit)) {
    fruits_counter[fruit] = 0
  }
  fruits_counter[fruit] += 1;
});

console.log('Mangos: ' + fruits_counter.Mango);
console.log('Naranjas: ' + fruits_counter.Orange);
console.log('Manzanas: ' + fruits_counter.Apple);
console.log('Melocotones: ' + (fruits_counter.Peach || 0));
```

En cada pasada de la iteración se inicializa la cantidad en `0` si es que esa propiedad no existe en el objeto (usando `hasOwnProperty`).

Comment: Hola Cesar muchas gracias, pero si quisiera saber la cantidad de varias frutas reutilizando la funcion como me quedaría? estuve intentando esto:
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];
var cant = fruits.filter(function(value, fruta) {

  return value == fruta;})


console.log(cant.length,"Orange");
console.log(cant.length,"Mango");

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar un bucle y un contador asi:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];
var oranges = 0;

fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
  if (fruit == "Orange") {
    oranges++;
  }
});

console.log(oranges);
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @alfredo destruye totalmente la estructura de programación funcional usando avoid effects mutando valores por fuera de la función, la respuesta de @César es muy buena es lo mas común, igualmente puedes usar un acumulador que vaya contando con reduce.

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];

const count = fruits.reduce((acumulator, current) => {
  return current === 'Orange' ? acumulator + 1 : acumulator;
}, 0);
console.log(count);
```

En programación funcional no se itera se usa recursividad aquí un ejemplo de como funciona map por dentro

```js
const map = ([head, ...tail], fn) => (
  typeof head === 'undefined' ? [] : [fn(head), ...map(tail, fn)]
);

const result = map([1, 2, 3], (x) => x * 2)

console.log(result);
```

como se puede ver regresa un Array al igual que filter por eso es que usando .length con filter nos regresa el count del valor buscado

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo este ejemplo con el método map

```js
 let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];

let counter = 0
fruits.map(el => {
  if(el === 'Orange'){
    counter = counter + 1
  }
})

console.log(`There are ${counter} oranges`)
```

> Al final con sintáxis de template strings mando imprimir el valor de
>   la variable en una cadena de texto; así mismo declaro la variable counter  > por fuera de recorrido de `map()` ya que de lo contrario por cada iteración > la variable se estaría redeclarando lo cual imposibilitaría el resultado   > que deseas obtener