# Reemplaza Funcion Flecha en ES5

Tags: javascript

Debido a que la pagina donde quiero insertar la siguiente linea de codigo, como puedo reemlazar la funcion flecha para que me pueda correr en la version ES5?

```
const frutas = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];

const contarFrutas = (valor, listaDeFrutas) => (
 listaDeFrutas.filter(fruta => fruta === valor).length
); 

 console.log(
 contarFrutas('Banana', frutas)
);

console.log(
 contarFrutas('Orange', frutas)
);
```

Comment: En mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184969/contar-dentro-de-un-array#184972) a tu pregunta anterior [Contar Dentro de un Array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184969/contar-dentro-de-un-array) lo hago de ambas formas.

Comment: aqui esta el como "use strict";

var frutas = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Orange"];

var contarFrutas = function contarFrutas(valor, listaDeFrutas) {
  return listaDeFrutas.filter(function (fruta) {
    return fruta === valor;
  }).length;
};

console.log(contarFrutas('Banana', frutas));

console.log(contarFrutas('Orange', frutas));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque eso está bien, realmente la sustitución sería:

```
function contarFrutas(valor, listaDeFrutas) {
  return listaDeFrutas.filter(function (fruta) {
    return fruta === valor;
  }).length;
};
```

Ya que no hace falta asignar la función a una variable, simplemente basta con declarar la función sin mas.

Y la llamarías como te han puesto en el otro comentario:

```
console.log(contarFrutas('Banana', frutas));
console.log(contarFrutas('Orange', frutas));
```

Answer (score 2):

Te lo dejo como ejecutable para que puedas revisarlo

```js
"use strict";

var frutas = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Orange"];

var contarFrutas = function contarFrutas(valor, listaDeFrutas) {
  return listaDeFrutas.filter(function (fruta) {
    return fruta === valor;
  }).length;
};

console.log(contarFrutas('Banana', frutas));

console.log(contarFrutas('Orange', frutas));
```

> Si mencionas el estándar ES5 pase incluso la declaración de variables
>   al tipo `var`, así mismo la declaración de las funciones flecha se paso a  > la declaración de funciones habituales